# Tensorflow: Getting same prediction for all rows with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, lstm

I am new to Tensorflow and have been playing around with the TF tutorials. One such tutorial is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series), which deals with time series forecasting of temperatures as a regression problem using LSTM. Instead,  I would want to convert the same into a classification problem - output 1 if temperature 12 hours from now is more than current temperature and 0 otherwise. However, all predictions seem to be outputting 0. This is not an imbalanced dataset (~50% equally split). Below is the code I am using:

```
import os
import math

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 6)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False


# In[2]:


zip_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    fname='jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip',
    extract=True)
csv_path, _ = os.path.splitext(zip_path)

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
df.head()


# In[3]:


TRAIN_SPLIT = 0.70
VAL_SPLIT = 0.20
tf.random.set_seed(13)


# In[4]:


def create_time_steps(length):
  return list(range(-length, 0))

# In[7]:


def baseline(history):
  return np.mean(history)


# In[8]:


features_considered = ['p (mbar)', 'T (degC)', 'rho (g/m**3)']
features = df[features_considered]
features.index = df['Date Time']
features.head()


# In[9]:


features.plot(subplots=True)


# In[10]:


dataset = features.values
len_train = math.floor(TRAIN_SPLIT * len(dataset))
len_val = math.floor(VAL_SPLIT * len(dataset))
data_mean = dataset[:len_train].mean(axis = 0)
data_std = dataset[:len_train].std(axis = 0)
dataset = (dataset - data_mean) / data_std


# In[11]:


def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step):
  data = []
  labels = []
  vals = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])
    target_var = 1 if target[i + target_size] > target[i - 1] else 0
    labels.append(target_var)
    vals.append(target[i + target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels), np.array(vals)


# In[12]:


past_history = 720
future_target = 72
STEP = 6

x_train, y_train, v_train = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 1], 0, len_train, past_history, future_target, STEP)
x_val, y_val, v_val = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 1], len_train, len_train + len_val, past_history, future_target, STEP)
x_test, y_test, v_test = multivariate_data(dataset, dataset[:, 1], len_train + len_val, None, past_history, future_target, STEP)

print(len(x_train), len(x_val), len(x_test))


# In[13]:


print ('Single window of past history : {}'.format(x_train[0].shape))


# In[15]:


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, input_shape = x_train.shape[-2:]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])


# In[16]:


print(model.predict(x_test[:1]).shape)


# In[26]:


EVALUATION_INTERVAL = 200
EPOCHS = 10

single_step_history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = EPOCHS,
                                steps_per_epoch = EVALUATION_INTERVAL,
                                validation_data = val_data,
                                validation_steps = 50)


# In[18]:


EVALUATION_INTERVAL = 200
EPOCHS = 1

single_step_history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=EPOCHS,
                                            steps_per_epoch=EVALUATION_INTERVAL,
                                            validation_data=val_data,
                                            validation_steps=50)


# Evaluate the model on the test data using `evaluate`
print('\n# Evaluate on test data')
results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size = 256)
print('Loss, Acc:', results)


# In[21]:


predictions = tf.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis = 1)
print('predictions shape:', predictions.shape)


# In[22]:


df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns = ['actual', 'prediction'])
df['actual'] = y_test
df['prediction'] = predictions.numpy()
df.head()

print(df.loc[:, 'prediction'].sum())
```

I have used a BinaryCrossEntropy loss and have tried 'tanh' and 'sigmoid' activations (in the output layer), but the output is always the same (0 for all rows). What might be wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the sigmoid activation will return a value between 0.0 and 1.0, this essentially represents that probability that the sample belongs to class 1.

To get the actual labels, instead of doing argmax, you need to check if it is > 0.5, if it is then that sample got assigned label=1, otherwise it got assigned label=0.

You can replace your initial assignment of predictions with the following:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = (predictions < 0.5).astype(np.int)
print('predictions shape:', predictions.shape)

df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns = ['actual', 'prediction'])
df['actual'] = y_test
df['prediction'] = predictions
df.head()

print(df.loc[:, 'prediction'].sum())
```

Hopefully this helps !